# Force soft keyboard to show on focused input in HTML

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, television

Currently I'm creating a smart TV app for several brands.
A local equipment shop is willing to let me test the app on their televisions.
All bugs I found aren't that hard to fix, except for one on the Panasonic devices.

The app is launched through the *Panasonic IPTV Apps Developers (HTML5) App* SDK.
I have a login screen with several input-fields, yet when one is focused the keyboard won't show.
Because of this I can not enter any information and I'm unable to leave or change my focus in the form.

The first input-field has an autofocus.
I removed the autofocus thinking it had something to do with a focus event not registering or something similar.
But after a manual interaction with the input-field, the field is focussed but there is no keyboard that shows up.

Example of my HTML input-field:

```
<!-- Input username -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" tabindex="1" autofocus>
    </div><!-- .col -->
</div><!-- .row -->
```

Example of my Javascript to autofocus the input-field (after a successful login, I navigate a ul (my menu) with the arrow keys of the TV remote, hence the tab-index and forced autofocus.)

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $("[autofocus]").focus();
});
```

Does anyone here know of another solution I can try that may resolve my problem?

Comment: Can you provide some code, here by just asking had no sign of pain you put?

Comment: @geminiousgoel , Does this help explain the problem to you? Or do you need extra/ other information?

Comment: autofocus is defined to work reliably only on page load. It is not really suited for situations where you are swapping, or opening, or unhiding DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

In javascript the **prompt()** opens the soft keyboard.

You can try opening the keyboard on focus event of the input field and to make it auto-focused you can do this.

```
$(textFiled).trigger("focus");
```

Also, wait for the DOM to load completely. Hopes this works for your device.

Comment: Will definitely try this, I am creating different versions for the next time I'm going to test at the shop.
If your answer works I will mark it as the answer.
But expect it to be in a few days.